# Deep Belief Network configuration for dice face recognition

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I should develop a network that can read the result of throwing a dice. I have a dataset which consists on a synthetic collection of such images, together with the corresponding target values. Each image has size 32x32 and is represented
as a vector of length 32x32=1024.

So far, I've created a training set by selecting at random 820 images with target 1, 820 with target 2, etc. (The whole data set contains 6x8200 images.)

Then I tried to follow this DBN implementation I found on the readme of [this github](https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/DeepLearnToolbox) , as follows:

```
rand('state',0)
%train dbn
dbn.sizes = [1000 1000 1000];
opts.numepochs =   5;
opts.batchsize = 120;
opts.momentum  =   0;
opts.alpha     =   1;
dbn = dbnsetup(dbn, train_x, opts);
dbn = dbntrain(dbn, train_x, opts);

%figure; visualize(dbn.rbm{1}.W');   %  Visualize the RBM weights

%unfold dbn to nn
nn = dbnunfoldtonn(dbn, 6);
nn.activation_function = 'sigm';

%train nn
opts.numepochs =  5;
opts.batchsize = 120;


[nn,L] = nntrain(nn, train_x, train_y, opts);
%[er, bad] = nntest(nn, train_x, train_y);

    nn.testing = 1;
    nn = nnff(nn, test_x, zeros(size(test_x,1), nn.size(end)));
    nn.testing = 0;
    [dummy, i] = max(nn.a{end},[],2);
    labels = i;

    [dummy, expected] = max(test_y,[],2);
    bad = find(labels ~= expected);    
    er = numel(bad) / size(test_x, 1);

net=nn.a{end}';
numRight = size(test_y, 1) - numel(bad');

fprintf('Accuracy: %.2f%%\n', numRight / size(test_y, 1) * 100);
```

The configuration was based on the one used in [Master Thesis of Rasmus Berg Palm on page 22](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6284/pdf/imm6284.pdf), even though it's using a different dataset.

I've used this implementation before on the dataset used in the thesis (the MNIST one) and I obtained good results, but for this problem I'm getting a strange result that the predicted results are almost always the same, so let's say it predicts all test elements as number 2, or all test elements as number 5, etc.

I believe it's because of my configuration, and not a problem with my implementation or anything code-wise (but maybe it is). Is there anything obviously wrong with these parameters values that I should change?